# Python - Convert Query to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, series

I'm quite new to Python and just getting to grips with using it for Big Data analysis.

I was wondering if it's possible to convert a query result to Dataframe.

My result is based on splitting splitting a prior string to obtain the count of occurrences

```
   database_desired = df_ddny.DatabaseDesireNextYear.apply(lambda x: pd.value_counts(str(x).split(";"))).sum(axis=0)
print(database_desired)
```

Output:

```
Microsoft SQL Server     9409.0
nan                     11632.0
MySQL                   14827.0
PostgreSQL              17023.0
MongoDB                 15221.0
Firebase                 8149.0
Redis                   11543.0
MariaDB                  5843.0
Elasticsearch            9870.0
Cassandra                4027.0
SQLite                  10422.0
dtype: float64
```

I just want to then have a DataFrame that would look like:

```
    DatabaseName     Count
Microsoft SQL Server    9409.0
MySQL                   14827.0
```

and so on.
I had tried creating a new DataFrame and inserting the results as a new column but the dataframe does not have the attribute I've used (I expected this)

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'Databases Worked':[df_ddny.DatabaseDesireNextYear]})
new_df['Count'] = df_ddny.DatabaseDesireNextYear.apply(lambda x: pd.value_counts(str(x).split(";"))).sum(axis=0)
new_df.info()
```

I've had a look at several other articles but can't quite configure it to my scenario.
Thanks!

Comment: something like this `database_desired.to_frame('Counts').reset_index().rename(columns={0:'DatabaseName'})` assuming `DatabaseName` field is the index for the current output

Comment: Does `pd.read_sql()` do what you want?

Comment: @ThePyGuy - Perfect! That's done the trick thank you :)

Comment: @ThePyGuy do you want to pop your comment in as an 'Answer' so I can mark as Solution

Comment: I added as an answer @craig157

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `to_frame` to create a frame out of it, you can pass column name to it, and finally reset the index, and rename the index column which becomes `0` after resetting.

```py
database_desired = database_desired.to_frame('Counts').reset_index().rename(columns={0:'DatabaseName'})
```